# Reference object instance inside of another object

Tags: java, object, instance

I have the following code at the end of my main class to initialize objects and start the program:

```
HumanPlayer humanPlayer = new HumanPlayer(baseHold);
Controller controller = new Controller(new ComputerPlayer(), humanPlayer, new Dice(seed));
controller.start();
```

Inside my Controller class, is the following code:

```
public class Controller
{
    int roller;
    public Controller(ComputerPlayer cpuPlayer, HumanPlayer userPlayer, Dice dice)
    {
    }
//....
}
```

I am unsure what to initialize above, as I've tried a few things already and it still does not find my object dice in the following code:

```
public void start()
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        roller = dice.roll();
        System.out.println("Die roll: " + roller);
    }
}
```

**roll** is a method within the Dice class.
Is there a particular way for me to tell it to look for dice as an object within my controller object instead of a variable within my controller object, or am I going about this completely wrong?

I want to be able to roll the die 5 times here.

error:

```
Controller.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                roller = dice.roll();
                         ^
symbol:   variable dice
location: class Controller    
1 error
```

Comment: Add stacktrace please (The actual error logs)

Comment: Just a heads up (not sure if this is the case with your actual code) you have a comma missing between `humanPlayer` and `new Dice(seed)` when you create an instance of `Controller`.

Comment: Fixed both, and edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `dice` as an instance field of `Controller`, like this:

```
public class Controller {
    private Dice dice;
    // rest of the class code
}
```

Then in the constructor you will do:

```
public Controller(ComputerPlayer cpuPlayer, HumanPlayer userPlayer, Dice dice) {
    // some other code
    this.dice = dice;
}
```

Then you can use `this.dice` in the other methods inside the `Controller` class.

Comment: This was my problem. This has fixed it, thank you. Someone with reputation please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
HumanPlayer humanPlayer = new HumanPlayer(baseHold);
Controller controller = new Controller(new ComputerPlayer(), humanPlayer new Dice(seed));
controller.start();
```

You need a comma between `humanPlayer` and `new Dice(seed)`

```
HumanPlayer humanPlayer = new HumanPlayer(baseHold);
Controller controller = new Controller(new ComputerPlayer(), humanPlayer, new Dice(seed));
controller.start();
```

Comment: Fixed the original code to reflect this. Same error.